# Math addition code, trying to end after correct answer

Tags: java

The problem I have is that after a correct answer, it still asks the question. What am I missing? I'm still new to JAVA right now and don't want to get discouraged by what is probably a simple error or oversight.

```
package acourtney;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hmwk03 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number1 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    int number2 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    int counter = 0;

    Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print ("What is " + number1 + " + " + number2 + " ? " + "(You have three chances) ");

    int answer = input.nextInt();

        if (number1 + number2 == answer)
            System.out.println("Answer is correct");

        else
            System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect. You have two chances left ");
            counter = 2; 

    System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " + " + number2 + " ? ");

    answer = input.nextInt();

        if (number1 + number2 == answer)

            System.out.println("Answer is correct");

        else
            System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect. You have one chance left");
        counter = 3;

        System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " + " + number2 + " ? ");

        answer = input.nextInt();

        if (number1 + number2 == answer)
            System.out.println("Answer is correct");

        else
            System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect, You have failed");

        }


}
```

Comment: Have you looked at any of the other questions about guessing a number in Java on here? Or have you at least stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Always add braces `{}`. Don't ignore them just because they aren't necessary.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that's a personal style choice.

Comment: @weston Until you add a second line and forget to add braces. I see that fairly often.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I recommend using an IDE that indents for you. You'll never see this mistake.

Comment: @weston I don't fall for this, but I see it fairly commonly here. I write Clojure with Cursive, so it's not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a beginner to Java, I recommend you pseudocode your program to give yourself a blueprint to work off of. It helps you to break down your code into smaller steps.

```
public class Hmwk03 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number1 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    int number2 = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    int counter = 2; // Define the number of chances they have, start at 2 since the first counter value is 0
    boolean answerCheck = false; // Define if they answer was right

    Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);

    // Generate a for loop with a counter starting at 0
    // The loop will run either if they have more chances left
    // OR when they have gotten the answer right
    for(int i = 0; i < counter || answerCheck == true; i++) {

        System.out.print ("What is " + number1 + " + " + number2 + " ? " + "(You have three chances) "); // Output the question

        int answer = input.nextInt(); // Receive the answer

        if (number1 + number2 == answer) { // if they got the right ansser
            // Make the answerCheck true or use break here                
            answerCheck = true; 
            System.out.println("Answer is correct"); // Output the user got the correct answer
            //break; This will also work to end the loop
        } else { // they got the wrong answer
            System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect. You have " + counter - i + " chances left."); // Note they got the answer wrong and tell them how many chances they have left 
        }
    }
    if(!answerCheck) System.out.print(" You have failed"); // If they failed to get the answer correct, print out final statement.

}
```

Comment: I originally decremented counter to show the number of turns left in the system.out.println, but what I meant to show was counter - i. The i value will increase with each turn of the loop, so for instance the first run i will be 0, so counter - i -> (2 - 0) 2 chances left, second run i = 1, counter - i (2 - 1) 1 chance left, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can end a method early with a `return` statement.

```
if (number1 + number2 == answer) {
    System.out.println("Answer is correct");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Exit the program after every correct answer.

```
if (number1 + number2 == answer){
            System.out.println("Answer is correct");
System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're executing

`if (number1 + number2 == answer)
System.out.println("Answer is correct");`

Then skipping

`else
 System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect. You have two chances left ");`

Then picking right back up again at `counter = 2`.

If you're writing an if/else clause that's more than one line of code (like, say everything that happens after you enter a statement that's not correct) you MUST put curly braces `{}` around the entire thing. Best practice is to use the curly braces even when the clause is only one line.

Answer (score 0):

So Java is going to run line by line, and what you have here is that once the user answers, the program then exits the if-statement, and *continues onwards towards the next if statement*

as demonstrated by

```
 int answer = input.nextInt();

    if (number1 + number2 == answer)
        System.out.println("Answer is correct");

    else
        System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect. You have two chances left ");
        counter = 2; 

System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " + " + number2 + " ? ");
```

To fix this problem (as well as the issue that you seem to have copy-and-pasted code which is never a good practice), I suggest something along the lines of

```
//int numOfTries is how many chances you want to give the user
for(int i = 0; i < numOfTries; i++){
    // Prompt the user for Input
    int answer = input.nextInt();

    // Check if the answer is correct
    if (number1 + number2 == answer){
        System.out.println("Answer is correct");
        //Now exit the for loop, we are done!
        return;
    }
    // What happens if the answer is not correct
    else{
        // Print out how many tries they have left as well
        System.out.println("Your answer is incorrect. You have" + i + "chance left");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

P.S. instead of `break;` you could also use `return;` or `System.exit(0);`

Comment: When i change my code to what you suggested, it tells me that "break" cannot be used outside of a loop or switch. I am using eclipse to run the code if that helps

Comment: Hey, in that case, just use "return;" and that should fix your problem. I've edited my solution accordingly